# Divide and conquer to multiply 2 n digit numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, computational-complexity

I am having trouble with finding a closed form to show that the divide and  conquer algorithm for multiplying 2 numbers is $O(n^{log_2(3)})$  We are given the recurrence relation that $f(n)=3f(n/2)+cn$ for some c such that $f(1)=c$ and we are supposed to create a generating function from this. I have seen the solution without using the generating function but we are told specifically to use one. We are given the hint that $a_k=f(2^{k-1})$ and when I try this I can not get a closed form for the generating function. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you've already obtained the recurrence relation, why don't you just prove by induction that $O(n^{\log_2 3})$ satisfies this recurrence relation?

Comment: The question specifically states to use the appropriate generating function.  I have seen and done the induction proof but can not work out the generating function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want $$F=\sum _{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=a_0+\sum _{n=1}^\infty (3a_{n-1}+c2^{n-1})x^n=c+(3x\sum _{n=0}^\infty a_{n}x^n)+(cx\sum _{n=0}^\infty 2^{n}x^{n})$$

Use the definition of $F$ and the geometric series. Solve for F.

Comment: I tried going up two terms for some reason and messed up some arithmetic and got confused.  Thank you very much!

Comment: I do have another question though.  How do I get from this generating function to saying that $f(n)$ is $O(n^{log_2(3)}$?

Comment: i have not done the entire calculation, but surely you will end up with a good denominator to break in pieces(partial fractions) or just one term. After you do that, you can use geometric series to get and exact value for $a_n$..and somehow must be related to $n^{log_2(3)}=3^{log_2(n)}$